# No output data in sinc3 filter simulation

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I have the following code for sinc3 digital filter in verilog:-

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module dec256sinc24b
(input mclk1, /* used to clk filter */
input reset, /* used to reset filter */
input mdata1, /* input data to be filtered */

output reg [15:0] DATA, /* filtered output*/
output reg data_en,
input [15:0] dec_rate
);

/* Data is read on negative clk edge */
reg [36:0] ip_data1;
reg [36:0] acc1;
reg [36:0] acc2;
reg [36:0] acc3;
reg [36:0] acc3_d2;
reg [36:0] diff1;
reg [36:0] diff2;
reg [36:0] diff3;
reg [36:0] diff1_d;
reg [36:0] diff2_d;

reg [15:0] word_count;

reg word_clk;
reg enable;

/*Perform the Sinc action*/
always @ (mdata1)
if(mdata1==0)
    ip_data1 <= 37'd0;
    /* change 0 to a -1 for twos complement */
else
    ip_data1 <= 37'd1;

/*Accumulator (Integrator)
Perform the accumulation (IIR) at the speed of the modulator.
Z = one sample delay MCLKOUT = modulators conversion bit rate */

always @ (negedge mclk1, posedge reset)
begin
    if (reset)
    begin
    /* initialize acc registers on reset*/
        acc1 <= 37'd0;
        acc2 <= 37'd0;
        acc3 <= 37'd0;
    end
    else
    begin
    /*perform accumulation process */
        acc1 <= acc1 + ip_data1;
        acc2 <= acc2 + acc1;
        acc3 <= acc3 + acc2;
    end
end

/*decimation stage (MCLKOUT/WORD_CLK) */
always @ (negedge mclk1, posedge reset)
begin
    if (reset)
        word_count <= 16'd0;
    else
    begin
        if ( word_count == dec_rate - 1 )
            word_count <= 16'd0;
        else
            word_count <= word_count + 16'b1;
    end
end

always @ ( negedge mclk1, posedge reset )
begin
if ( reset )
    word_clk <= 1'b0;
else
begin
    if ( word_count == dec_rate/2 - 1 )
        word_clk <= 1'b1;
    else if ( word_count == dec_rate - 1 )
        word_clk <= 1'b0;
    end
end

/*Differentiator (including decimation stage)
Perform the differentiation stage (FIR) at a lower speed.
Z = one sample delay WORD_CLK = output word rate */

always @ (negedge word_clk, posedge reset)
begin
    if(reset)
    begin
        acc3_d2 <= 37'd0;
        diff1_d <= 37'd0;
        diff2_d <= 37'd0;
        diff1 <= 37'd0;
        diff2 <= 37'd0;
        diff3 <= 37'd0;
    end
    else
    begin
        diff1 <= acc3 - acc3_d2;
        diff2 <= diff1 - diff1_d;
        diff3 <= diff2 - diff2_d;
        acc3_d2 <= acc3;
        diff1_d <= diff1;
        diff2_d <= diff2;
    end
end

/* Clock the Sinc output into an output register
WORD_CLK = output word rate */

always @ (negedge word_clk )
begin
    case ( dec_rate )
        16'd32:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[15:0] == 16'h8000) ? 16'hFFFF : {diff3[14:0], 1'b0};
        end
        16'd64:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[18:2] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[17:2];
        end
        16'd128:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[21:5] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[20:5];
        end
        16'd256:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[24:8] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[23:8];
        end
        16'd512:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[27:11] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[26:11];
        end
        16'd1024:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[30:14] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[29:14];
        end
        16'd2048:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[33:17] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[32:17];
        end
        16'd4096:begin
        DATA <= (diff3[36:20] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[35:20];
        end
        default:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[24:8] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[23:8];
        end
    endcase
end

/* Synchronize Data Output*/
always@ (negedge mclk1, posedge reset )
begin
    if ( reset )
    begin
        data_en <= 1'b0;
        enable <= 1'b1;
    end
    else
    begin
        if ( (word_count == dec_rate/2 - 1) && enable )
        begin
            data_en <= 1'b1;
            enable <= 1'b0;
        end
        else if ( (word_count == dec_rate - 1)  && ~enable )
        begin
            data_en <= 1'b0;
            enable <= 1'b1;
        end
        else
            data_en <= 1'b0;
    end
end

endmodule
```

I have written a testbench for the same, with the following inputs: mclk1 = 10MHz, mdata1 = 5MHz and dec_rate = 64

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

`define SIM_CYCLE 8192

module sinc3_tb;

//Inputs
reg mclk1;
reg reset;
reg mdata1;
reg [15:0] dec_rate;

//outputs
wire [15:0] DATA;
wire data_en;

//debug

wire [36:0] diff3 = dec256sinc24b_inst.diff3;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
dec256sinc24b dec256sinc24b_inst(
    .mclk1(mclk1),
    .reset(reset),
    .dec_rate(dec_rate),
    /*************************************/
    .mdata1(mdata1),
    .DATA(DATA),
    .data_en(data_en)
);

/*************************************/

// mclk1 = 10MHz
always#(50)
begin
    mclk1 <= ~mclk1;
end

// mdata1 = 5MHz
always@(posedge mclk1)
begin
    mdata1 <= ~mdata1;
end

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    mclk1 = 1'b0;
    reset = 1'b0;
    mdata1 = 1'b0;
    dec_rate = 16'd64;
        
    // Add stimulus here
    #5 reset = 1'b1;

    #(`SIM_CYCLE) $finish;
end

endmodule
```

When I run the simulation, I don't get any output for the `DATA` and `diff3` as seen in the simulation below. Any suggestions how should I fix this issue?

[image]

Also why is the dec_rate = 40? Since, I have set it to 64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are driving the reset from your testbench.  Your design uses an active-high reset, but your testbench sets the reset to 1 for most of the simulation, keeping the design always in reset.

You need to invert the polarity of the `reset` signal inside the testbench.  Assert the reset at time 0, then release the reset at time 5:

```
initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    mclk1 = 1'b0;
    reset = 1'b1;
    mdata1 = 1'b0;
    dec_rate = 16'd64;
        
    // Add stimulus here
    #5 reset = 1'b0;

    #(`SIM_CYCLE) $finish;
end
```

Also, run your simulation for more time to see `DATA` change from 0.  For example:

```
`define SIM_CYCLE 8192*10
```

If you want to run for 1ms:

```
`define SIM_CYCLE 1_000_000
```

Your waveform display is set to hexadecimal format.  `40` is `0x40`, which is the same as 64 decimal.

Answer (score 1):

DATA is stuck at 0 because its re-timed by word_clk, and word_clk is stuck at 0.
The signal word_clk is stuck at 0 because reset is high and it holds word_clk at 0.

You are also not running it for enough time to see any data come out.
Try runing for 8192*8 rather than 8192 cycles.

The entire design is held in reset forever.

[image]

By the way its bad practice to generate clocks using always blocks in your RTL.  It might work in simulation and not in a synthesis/build flow.
A best practice is to use an PLL or MMCM or other vendor apparatus to generate your clocks.

Express time in ms like this:

```
localparam NUM_MS = 2;
// other code       
#(NUM_MS*1ms);
```